# Как указать браузеру, что это уже другой PHP скрипт?

Tags: php, браузер, кэширование

Я хочу ограничить количество одновременных обработок запросов в PHP до одной или двух с одного IP адреса. Под обработкой подразумевается обработка, к примеру, прогой Imagick (ImageMagick для PHP), например, сильное размытие (blur) большой картинки, что занимает достаточно много времени и, следовательно, сильно грузит процессор и приводит его в полный стопор.

Написал простой php скрипт с записью IP пользователя в Mysql.
И вот что он делает:

1. Получение IP пользователя
2. Проверка, есть ли он в базе
3. Если есть больше двух таких же IP, то показать посетителю сообщение, что запускать две обработки одновременно нельзя. Остановить дальнейшее выполнение php-скрипта.
4. Если такого IP нет - записать его в БД
5. Обработать картинку, и пусть обработка будет длится 25 секунд, т.е. заменил функцией sleep() (задержка в секундах)
6. После обработки (не важно успешной или нет) удалить IP из БД
7. Всё, отключиться от Mysql.

Объясняю суть проблемы: если создать в браузере 3 вкладки (оганичение-то не более двух одновременно в PHP) с адресом текущего скрипта, просто вставив его из буфера обмена и вручную запустить их поочерёдно (то есть просто запустить копии этого php-скрипта), то каждый скрипт почему-то ждёт предыдущего, пока он не завершится, а в БД после их запуска добавляется только одна запись и лишь через 25 секунд добавляются остальные! Выходит, что можно запустить хоть 20 обработок и они не будут ограничены!

Если в базу заранее добавить 10 таких одинаковых ip, то скрипт моментально показывает, что нельзя производить две одновременных обработки, то есть работает как надо, если в БД уже есть два или больше двух одинаковых IP.

Если этот скрипт запускать в разных браузерах, то тоже работает нормально - две одинаковых записи в базу данных добавляются практически моментально после запуска. А вот в одном браузере не получается - каждый последний запущенный скрипт как-бы ждёт завершения предыдущего и записи IP в БД добавляются только через 25 секунд.

Если назвать копии этого скрипта по-разному, например: script1.php, script2.php и script3.php а затем запустить их также сразу вручную и в одном и том же браузере, то тоже работает правильно - записи в БД добавляются как раз после того, как я их запустил, а не через 25 сек и без ожидания завершения предыдущего (выходит + 1-3 секунды, в зависимости как быстро их вручную запускать по очереди).

У меня только есть подозрение, что где-то надо сбрасывать какую-то сессию или что-то в этом роде, так как несколько запущенных копий скрипта в одном браузере не ограничиваются, а если запустить в разных браузерах - всё работает правильно!

Что может мешать добавлять сразу два ip в БД после одновременного запуска двух копий одного и того же скрипта в браузере?
(вместо этого IP из 1-го скрипта добавляется как надо сразу, а 2-й IP из второго скрипта только тогда, когда завершается 1-й скрипт)

Comment: Условие `if($row_cnt >= 2)` замените на `if($row_cnt > 2)`

Comment: Спасибо, но это ничего не меняет, было больше или равно 2 (затронет 2, 3, 4, 5...), а вы мне предлагаете просто больше 2 (затронет 3, 4, 5...). Ведь я всё равно смогу запустить 10 скриптов одновременно в браузере и не будут ограничены и будут работать.

Comment: просто в вопросе у вас `Если есть больше двух таких же IP, то показать посетителю сообщение,`, то есть несоответствие.

Comment: Я так и подумал, но я ведь я всё равно смогу запустить 10 скриптов одновременно в браузере и они не будут ограничены и будут работать, т.к. почему-то записи в БД будут добавляться по очереди, то есть ip 2-го запущенного скрипта запишется в БД только тогда когда добавится и удалится ip 1-го запущенного скрипта и так далее.

Comment: это у вас полный код скрипта? Вы именно его тестировали?

Comment: Да, я даже после того как сюда выложил - снова скопировал себе, подставил свой пароль, имя пользователя баз данных и попробовал запустить.

Comment: Прочитал вопрос более внимательно. Может дело в кешировании на стороне браузера? Попробуйте в начало скрипта дописать установку заголовков: `  header('Expires: Thu, 21 Jul 1977 07:30:00 GMT');
 header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
 header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
 header('Pragma: no-cache');` отменяющих кеширование.

Comment: К сожалению, добавление всех перечисленных header не помогло, я даже пробовал полностью очистить кэши браузеров Firefox и Opera. Но это что-то уже близко, ведь 2 записи добавляются одновременно если запустить по одному скрипту в разных браузерах (так было и без добавления header).

Comment: посмотрите, у вас сессии точно не используются автоматом? В куках сессионной переменной нет случайно?

Comment: Ну я снова очистил кэш, перезапустил браузеры, просмотрел список cookies ничего нет, затем запустил один скрипт - кук не появилось ни во время обработки ни после, также запускал 3 скрипта сразу - куки не появились. Зашёл на гугл - появились 3 куки. Получается скрипт куки не шлёт. Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Попробовал такое: запустил скрипт -> очистил кэш браузера -> запустил второй скрипт -> очистил кэш браузера -> запустил третий скрипт - на нём (на 3-м), как и надо показало сообщение, что количество одновременных обработок ограничено, посмотрел в БД - там 2 записи создались одновременно (как и надо), тоесть с такими манипуляциями заработало правильно, появились сразу две записи и потом удалились как положено, 3-й запуск скрипта был так сказать остановлен. Теперь вот я даже не знаю, как я понял, надо смотреть что там создает у себя браузер, но понятия не имею что...

Comment: И вот ещё что получилось методом тыка и без очистки кэша браузера: запустил скрипт 1 -> закрыл вкладку браузера -> создал новую вкладку и запустил скрипт 2 -> закрыл её -> создал опять новую вкладку и запустил скрипт 3 и тут опа: Извините, но с вашего компа уже идёт обработка! И в БД также как и надо уже появились две записи (больше двух быть и не должно). А вот если запускать скрипты по очереди, не закрывая вкладки, то всё равно ничего не получается.

Comment: Вы лучше на сервере проверьте, к вам три запроса приходит при открытии трех вкладок из одного браузера без очистки кеша одновременно или последовательно? А то может проблемы нет, запросы приходят последовательно, каждый после выполнения предыдущего, то есть дополнительной нагрузки на сервер нет, работает всего 1 копия скрипта.

Comment: Я, честно говоря, не знаю, где это смотреть (использую Ubuntu с LAMP). Я запускаю один и тот же скрипт... Если просто открыть две копии одного и того же скрипта в Firefox, то есть два раза почти одновременно открыть скрипт_1, то записи в БД добавляются последовательно, то есть второй скрипт ждёт завершения первого (а так не надо, т.к. и IP первого из БД удаляется). А вот если также запустить одну копию в Firefox, а другую в Opera - записи добавляются одновременно, как и надо. И это есть проблема!

Comment: да хотя бы в самом начале скрипта поставьте вывод времени через echo и запустите скрипт в трех вкладках браузера одновременно. Если разница будет в ~25 сек между каждой следующей и текущей вкладками, то значит на сервере выполняется только 1 скрипт за раз и ни какой дополнительной нагрузки на него нет.

Comment: Хм, да, я запустил их почти одновременно, ну пусть даже с интервалом 1 секунда, но судя по времени 09:46:01 (запуск 1) -> 09:46:26 (запуск 2 через 1 секунду) -> 09:46:51 (запуск 3 через 1 секунду) они действительно выполняются по очереди каждый через 25 секунд как не крути и причём получение и отображение времени разместил в самом начале кода. И что делать, чтобы их разделить?

Comment: зачем вам их делить, если нагрузки на сервер нет? **Выполняется только один скрипт в текущем моменте времени**. А причина: возможно браузер так себя ведет при открытии одной и той же ссылки. Можно еще проверить как будет открываться одновременно страница с параметрами, например `?test=1`, `?test=2` и `?test=2` в адресной строке.

Comment: О да - с передачей разных запросов это заработало на отлично. По идее если разные POST запросы посылать это тоже сработает? Я так понимаю, надо сделать что-нибудь, чтоб браузеру было видно, что это уже другая страница?

Comment: думаю с POST запросами вообще проблем не должно быть.

Comment: Пипец, утэто да, я почти сутки гадал, впервые в интернете вопрос о php опубликовал, а оно вон что. Спасибо вам большое :)

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Вы бы код написали, возможно нормальная логика в вопросе имеет какую-то неточность в исполнении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно, дело в сессии.

PHP не начнет обрабатывать новый запрос, если не завершена работа с сессией предыдщуего, т.к. файл сессии заблокирован первым запросом. Это сделано для того, чтобы два обработчика не писали одновременно в один и тот же файл.

Чтобы следующий запрос стал обрататываться при еще не завершившейся обработке предыдущего, требуется в первом запросе закрыть файл сессии с помощью функции 
[session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-write-close.php). В Вашем случае это надо сделать перед запуском обработки изображения. Разумеется, после вызова этой функции Вы уже не сможете ничего записать в сессию в текущем обработчике.

Comment: Вот это чёткий ответ - 100% то, что мне надо!